# Check if a stage is already open before open it again javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to open  a stage by clicking a button, but before opening it, I want to check if the stage is already opened, then popup the opened stage to the front instead of opening a new one(no multi open of the same Stage).

```
@FXML
private void btn_Validate(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/scontrols/students/StudentManagement.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        StudentManagementController sendTo =  loader.getController();
        sendTo.receiveFromCamera(txtPictureName.getText());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
         if(!stage.isShowing())
         {
             stage.show();}

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebCamController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the new constructed stage be shown without the call of show?

Comment: @MarcusBleil, that is why I posted the question, so I can get the answer from the great guys like you out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking `!stage.isShowing()` on the *newly created* `Stage`. This will never do what you want. You need to keep a reference to the other `Stage` and keep using that reference.

```
public class Controller {

  private Stage otherStage;

  @FXML
  private void btn_Validate(ActionEvent event) {
    if (otherStage == null) {
      Parent root = ...;

      otherStage = new Stage();
      otherStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      otherStage.show();

    } else if (otherStage.isShowing()) {
      otherStage.toFront();
    } else {
      otherStage.show();
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to keep the `Stage` in memory when it's closed, then you can alter the above slightly.

```
public class Controller {

  private Stage otherStage;

  @FXML
  private void btn_Validate(ActionEvent event) {
    if (otherStage == null) {
      Parent root = ...;

      otherStage = new Stage();

      otherStage.setOnHiding(we -> otherStage = null);

      otherStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      otherStage.show();

    } else {
      otherStage.toFront();
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to store a reference to the loaded controller as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: These methods worked for me in case the new stage didnt get iconified, in the other case, the stage won't get to front. So I added this code : `if (newStage.isIconified())
                newStage.setIconified(false);
            newStage.toFront();`